# Wrong input to Line[] crashes the Front End

Tags: graphics, bugs, front-end, crash

**WARNING:** The code in this post crashes the Front End on my computer, causing all unsaved work to be lost. Be sure to save your work before trying this out!

---

```
lines = Table[Line[{{i, 0}, {i, -1}}], {i, 0.1, 1, 0.1}];
Graphics[{lines}]
```

[image]

If, however, the outer set of braces are inadvertently omitted in the `Line[]` as follows:

```
lines = Table[Line[{i, 0}, {i, -1}], {i, 0.1, 1, 0.1}];
```

Then Mma 12.2 crashes as soon as the Graphics command is executed. Can someone verify this? Please include your version info as well. Thanks.

---

```
$Version
```

> "12.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)"

**--------------------------------------------**

**Edit:** To include InfiniteLine and HalfLine behavior with missing outer braces

(This doesn't crash my FrontEnd, but be careful on your systems)

```
lines2a = Table[InfiniteLine[{{i, 0}, {i, -1}}], {i, 0.1, 1, 0.1}];
lines2b = Table[InfiniteLine[{i, 0}, {i, -1}], {i, 0.1, 1, 0.1}];
```

lines2b has a missing set of braces.

```
g2a = Graphics[lines2a, Frame -> Automatic, 
   PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}];
g2b = Graphics[lines2b, Frame -> Automatic, 
   PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}];
GraphicsRow[{g2a, g2b}]
```

[image]

Also replacing the `InfiniteLine` in the above experiment with `HalfLine` results in the same behavior, so I won't add it again.

Comment: Yes, it crashes in ``12.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 24, 2021)``.

Comment: Also crashes on macOS (12.2. or 12.3.1). Please report this to Wolfram.

Comment: @Szabolcs, my apologies. I did include the crash tag. I had been trying to figure out what went wrong on my computer for the past several hours.

Comment: No worries, I didn't lose work this time (as I understood what was going to happen) but I have in the past. It is common that people don't read in detail before trying a few lines of code. Front End crashes are much more dangerous than kernel crashes because they lead to lost work. I added the warning for the benefit of other readers.

Comment: This is a regression in the newer versions; in my v. 12.0.0 on Win10-64 this only causes the expected error.

Comment: Just chiming in that this also breaks with 12.3.0 on Linux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the bug.  This is fixed in the upcoming 13.0 release (which I expect to be shipping in the next several weeks from the time of this writing).  The correct behavior for your `Line` example is to produce a pink box with a tooltip indicating the syntax error, and it now does.

[image]

Note that your `InfiniteLine` example does not produce a pink box because there is no syntax error.  The version of `InfiniteLine` without the braces has a different, documented meaning.

Comment: Perfect. Many thanks. Only much later did I realize the other usage for `InfiniteLine`.

Comment: Where can I see the update list of v13.0 in advance?